# How can I find the min date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I find the minimum date when the date format is dd-MM-yyyy like below. The output should return the min date from the dates below.

var a = "12-31-2018"
var b = "12-31-2019"

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `Date.parse` to convert the date strings into bona fide dates.  Then, compare them:

```js
var a = "12/31/2018";
var b = "12/31/2019";

var dateA = Date.parse(a);
var dateB = Date.parse(b);

var dateMin = dateA < dateB ? a : b;
console.log("minimum date is " + dateMin);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I need the exact format to be printed like 12-31-2018

Comment: Tim - var a, var b are dynamic. They can have any dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Date objects using those two strings, compare them and return the older one.

```js
function olderDate(dateA, dateB) {
  var date1 = new Date(dateA);
  var date2 = new Date(dateB);
  if (date1 < date2)
    return dateA;
  else
    return dateB;
}
console.log(olderDate("12/31/2018", "12/31/2019"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function olderDate(dateA, dateB) {
  var date1 = new Date(dateA);
  var date2 = new Date(dateB);
  if (date1 < date2)
    return dateA;
  else
    return dateB;
}
console.log(olderDate("12/31/2018", "12/31/2019"));
```